# How to call a cloud function within a cloud function AND include data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call cloud function "startTimer" from another cloud function and *include data* while calling function "startTimer"

On my client side, for example, it is easy to call the function "startTimer" and include data by writing the following (flutter code):

```
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('startTimer');
callable.call({"gameId": MyFirebase.gameId});
```

I am then able to retrieve the data within my cloud function "startTimer" by doing the following:

```
exports.startTimer = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const gameId = data.gameId;
```

How would I be able to call the function "startTimer" in another cloud function and include data (gameId)? Moreover, how I would I do this so that the data is exactly formatted/structured like in the code snippet above (data.gameId)?
I tried something like this, and it doesn't work:

```
fetch("https://{LOCATION}-{PROJECT-ID}.cloudfunctions.net/startTimer", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({"gameId": gameId}),)};
```

"fetch" comes from
`const fetch = require("node-fetch");`

I'm pretty new to javascript/typescript, so any help/references is much appreciated :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Renaud's, you can also use [Google Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) to call your HTTP functions. The major benefit of doing so will be that you can return the response from your first functions without waiting for the completion of second. It's a minor thing but I've found it helpful in many cases.

You can pass any data to the GCloud task's body that you thing maybe needs so you don't have to make calls to database from the second function again.

```
exports.firstFunctions = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Functions logic
  await addCloudTask(/*params*/)
  //Return the response
})


const addCloudTask = async (queue, url, method, inSeconds, body) => {
  const project = "<project-id>"
  const location = "us-central1"
  const parent = gCloudClient.queuePath(project, location, queue)

  const [response] = await gCloudClient.createTask({
    parent,
    task: {
      httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: method,
        url,
        body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({body})).toString("base64"),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      },
      scheduleTime: {
        seconds: inSeconds + (Date.now() / 1000)
      }
    }
  });
  return
}
```

You can also pass the `inSeconds` parameter to add any delay for the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possibilities:

##### 1. Call it as an HTTP endpoint following the protocol

As you will read in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference), "An `https.onCall` trigger for Cloud Functions is an HTTPS trigger **with a specific format for the request and response**. "

So you could call the Callable Cloud Function, from another Cloud Function, with e.g. Axios or fetch.

##### 2. Use an extra Pub/Sub Cloud Function

You can refactor your business logic in one function, that you call from two Cloud Functions: the already existing Callable Cloud Function or [a Pub/Sub triggered Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events). Something along the following lines, with an asynchronous business logic and the use of async/await:

```
exports.startTimer = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const gameId = data.gameId;
        const result = await asyncBusinessLogic(gameId);
        return { result: result }
    } catch (error) {
        // ...
    }
});

exports.startTimerByPubSubScheduler = functions.pubsub.topic('start-timer').onPublish((message) => {

    try {
        const gameId = message.json.gameId;
        await asyncBusinessLogic(gameId);
        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        // ...
        return null;
    }
});


async function asyncBusinessLogic(gameId) {
    
    const result = await anAsynchronousJob(gameId);
    return result;
    
}
```

Comment: Hey @JeffreyWolberg, did you have time to look at the proposed solutions?